# Audio resources wont play after export to jar

Tags: java, audio, intellij-idea, jar, resources

Okay, so I have a simple program that loads audio files and plays them.

I have this for loading my audio files

```
Clip c1 = null;
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(songPaths[k + 1]).getAbsoluteFile());
        c1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        c1.open(audioInputStream);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It runs fine in my intelliJ, and when I look to build artifacts and try to run the jar that's made it fails to load the resources. My songPaths array looks like this:

```
private final String[] songPaths = {"res/fcpOriginal.wav", "res/fcpRemix.wav",
                                    "res/ibizaOriginal.wav", "res/ibizaRemix.wav",
                                    "res/pohOriginal.wav", "res/pohRemix.wav",
                                    "res/sugarOriginal.wav", "res/sugarRemix.wav",
                                    "res/wavesOriginal.wav", "res/wavesRemix.wav"};
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. **FOR ANY FUTURE RESEARCHERS!**

I changed

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(songPaths[k + 1]).getAbsoluteFile());
```

to

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass.getResource(songPaths[k + 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding your directory hierarchy correctly, you have the following:

src

out/artifacts/nameOfProject_jar.

res

You should put a copy of your res folder in to the nameOfProject_jar folder. Because the working directory for your application is now your nameOfProject_jar folder, so when you are using relative paths like you are, it will look for the res folder in nameOfProject_jar directory instead. :)